# how can I delete my child row in sql if it's failing?

Tags: mysql

When I execute the next SQL code:

```
delete from product where idproduct = 2;
```

I get the next error:

```
Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`store`.`sale_detail`, CONSTRAINT `fk_sale_detail_product1` FOREIGN KEY (`idproduct`) REFERENCES `product` (`idproduct`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

when I try to delete the child of my table dont want, but however I just want to delete product rows without delete brands..

- Image of brand table: [Brand table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTrid.png)
- Image of product table: [Product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG4S4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't since that violates `Referencial Integrity Constraint` rule. You should chose cascading option saying `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

1. You need to delete the child row first and then delete the parent row.
2. You can temporarily disable FK check saying `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` and enable them once done with deletion.
3. Drop all FK constraint, perform `delete` and then recreate FK constraint again.
4. Best option: Go for a soft delete by having a `Status` column in your table and just update that column to `Deleted` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key constraint on your store.sale_detail table in the idproduct column. So if you are trying to delete a product you need to be sure that product is not referenced on the sale_detail table.

Another solution is to modify your foreign key so when you delete a row on the product table the referenced row on the sale_detail gets NULL on the corresponding column. Actually you have:

```
ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

But you can have:

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Also, you can force to delete all references on the sale_detail table:

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I set the fk with restrict. I dont know if i am ok, but it works

Comment: with restrict you are going to have the same problem that you posted on the beginning. Restrict means that if you have a reference on the foreign key then you can't delete the referenced row (exact as your original problem).